# C++ dynamic array of string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am learning C++ coming over from Objective-C / C, and for a dummy project I want to load the words from the `/usr/share/dict/words` file stored on Mac OS X machines.

The idea is to load the file and get each word into an array, so I have an `array` of type `string`.

But I'm having trouble working correctly with dynamic memory with my arrays - using `new` and `delete`. I've added some of the code below, if anyone could help out...

And so I'm getting a memory error:

```
word:: A
word:: a
word:: aa
word:: aal
definitions(2758) malloc: *** error for object 0x100103b90: incorrect 
checksum for freed object - object was 
probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Load words:

```
string* Definition::loadWords()
{
    int arrayLength = 0;

    arrayOfWords = new string[arrayLength];

    ifstream file;

    file.open("/usr/share/dict/words");

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        while(file.good()){
            string word;
            getline( file, word );
            this->addWord(word, arrayOfWords, &arrayLength);
        }

    }

    file.close();

    cout << endl << "There are " << arrayLength << " words" << endl;

    return arrayOfWords;
};
```

Add words to array:

```
void Definition::addWord(string newWord, string currentArray[], int* arrayLength)
{
    cout << endl << "word:: " << newWord;

    string *placeholderArray = new string[*arrayLength + 1];
    placeholderArray[*arrayLength + 1] = newWord;

    for(int i = 0; i < *arrayLength; i++){
        placeholderArray[i] = currentArray[i];
    }

    (*arrayLength)++;

    currentArray = placeholderArray;

    delete [] placeholderArray;
}
```

Comment: Switch to using vectors instead of using dynamic memory directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing I can see is this:

```
placeholderArray[*arrayLength + 1] = newWord;
```

You are adding an element past the end of the array. Arrays are indexed from 0. For example if the array length is 5 then the last element in the array is at index 4. So the line should be:

```
placeholderArray[*arrayLength] = newWord;
```

Then after that you are deleting your array with this:

```
currentArray = placeholderArray;

delete [] placeholderArray;
```

Since you are just setting currentArray to point to placeholderArray and then deleting it.

Also passing by reference is much better than passing by pointer. So rather than this:

```
void Definition::addWord(string newWord, string currentArray[], int* arrayLength)
```

Use this:

```
void Definition::addWord(string newWord, string currentArray[], int& arrayLength)
```

That you don't always have to use the * to get the value each time you want to use it.

Here's a tutorial on using references:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/

Also save yourself the time and effort and learn to use vectors and stl containers rather than arrays sooner rather than later.

Here's a tutorial for using vectors:
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm

Comment: Hi, thanks, you're incorrect about your first observation, I am using arrayLength + 1 which is from the previous array, I've already created a new array with +1 elements, the idea was to put the new word last before I copy the previous arrays words from 0 to n - 1. Thank you for pointing out about reference vs pointers, I missed that.

Comment: Try step through your program and you will see what I'm saying. arrayLength starts at 0, you then add a string which passes 0 as arrayLength. You the create an array of length arrayLength+1 (1) and then you add an element at arrayLength+1 (1), which means you have just added an element beyond the end of the array. So you should be creating the array of length 1 and adding element at index 0.

Comment: Actually, David's correct there.  For instance, the first time the method is called, you would create array[1].  Then you set a value to array[1], which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

```
currentArray = placeholderArray;
```

This aliases placeholderArray to currentArray.  So, when you call...

```
delete [] placeholderArray;
```

.. you are deleting what currentArray is pointing to.

Comment: So what I should be doing is not deleting it, but then I still have a crash, I run out of memory

Comment: Does your assignment require you to use dynamic arrays in this way?  If you can use vectors, that would be easier.

Comment: There's no assignment, actually I'm just trying to master dynamic memory, which is why this vector solution isn't interesting for me right now.

Comment: In that case, return the second array and delete the original.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are simply assigning the *pointer*, as opposed to the values in the array:

```
currentArray = placeholderArray;
```

And here you free the space pointed to by said pointer:

```
delete [] placeholderArray;
```

The next time you to read from the freed memory space will result in undefined behavior.

---

Instead of using C-style arrays in C++, use `std::vector` and its `resize()` function. Better still, your application could simply invoke `push_back()` on each `newWord`, which will obviate the entire need for your `addWord()` function.